# How to save requests and responses to database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, aop

I would like to write an aspect or something like that and whenever a request comes to the controller it saves the request and the response to the database.

First question is what type I should use in my entity for request and response ( string, blob, etc)

Second question, how to get request,response and its controller name  to create the entity to save to database ?

Lastly, is it possible to calculate response time (time spent in the controller) of the controller ?

Answer (score 4):

This kinda expands on the other answers, but I think It warrants a separate answer.

If your pulling in spring-boot-starter-web, then you're already pulling in spring-aop. If your going to go down the point cut route though, I'd highly recommend just using the Micrometer `@Timed` annotation which comes with `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. I've written my own metric pointcuts a many times, but if your just after timings and counts of successes and failures, `@Timed` works great.

I'd also highly recommend looking into using a time series database (e.g [influx](https://www.influxdata.com/products/influxdb/)) for storing things like response times and other performance metrics. Keep your raw payloads and other possible auditing concerns in a separate DB. There are some very powerful things you can do with influx and running [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) or [Chronograf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/chronograf/) on top of it. Without a doubt one of the best things my current company has done is years is adopting Influx/Chronograf.

With regards to the request/response capture, I had a weird edge case in my work flow once where the http trace just wasn't working for some hard requirements. You can capture the contents directly in a chain filter yourself with a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`
Then you can access them with:

```
 @Component
class MyPayloadCapturingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request)
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response)

        filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper)

        def requestBody = new String(requestWrapper.contentAsByteArray)
        def responseBody = new String(responseWrapper.contentAsByteArray)
        //..do something with them
    }
}
```

note the `OncePerRequestFilter`, I found times when my Filter was firing multiple times for the same request. This prevents that.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer and it works. However, I have no idea how I can get response time ?

Answer (score 2):

> First question is what type I should use in my entity for request and
> response ( string, blob, etc)

It mainly depends on the database vendor and request/response length. 
String may be limited for some vendors and blob is so required.
On the other hand, matching on blob is slower.
Another alternative is using a nosql format such as JSON.

> Second question, how to get request,response and its controller name
> to create the entity to save to database ?

There are really several ways.
You could take advantage of built-in Spring Boot [http tracing features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-http-tracing) but it has a limitation : posted/received of request/responses are not available.

> 5.8. HTTP Tracing
>
> HTTP Tracing can be enabled by providing a bean of type
> HttpTraceRepository in your application’s configuration. For
> convenience, Spring Boot offers an InMemoryHttpTraceRepository that
> stores traces for the last 100 request-response exchanges, by default.
> InMemoryHttpTraceRepository is limited compared to other tracing
> solutions and we recommend using it only for development environments.
> For production environments, use of a production-ready tracing or
> observability solution, such as Zipkin or Spring Cloud Sleuth, is
> recommended. Alternatively, create your own HttpTraceRepository that
> meets your needs.
>
> The httptrace endpoint can be used to obtain information about the
> request-response exchanges that are stored in the HttpTraceRepository.
>
> 5.8.1. Custom HTTP tracing
>
> To customize the items that are included in each trace, use the
> management.trace.http.include configuration property. For advanced
> customization, consider registering your own HttpExchangeTracer
> implementation.

Alternatives are implementing a filter for requests/responses and log in it.
For example :

```
@Component
public class RequestResponseStoringFilter implements Filter {
    
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    } finally {
       // Measure elapsed time
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
       // store request data and store response data in a DB
       .....
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {}

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```

> Lastly, is it possible to calculate response time (time spent in the
> controller) of the controller ?

The way implement a Filter can do that as shown above.
The httptrace endpoint way provides that with the `timeTaken` field.   
FIY, here is the content of a [HttpTrace](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/trace/http/HttpTrace.html) instance :

```
HttpTrace.Principal getPrincipal() 
HttpTrace.Request   getRequest() 
HttpTrace.Response  getResponse() 
HttpTrace.Session   getSession() 
Instant getTimestamp() 
Long    getTimeTaken()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then, create an `Around` aspect for your controllers' methods' execution:

```
    @Around("within(path.to.your.controller.*)")
    public Object pointcutWithin(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        logger.info(" ###### pointcutWithin() before");
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

        logger.info(" ###### pointcutWithin() after");
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        long timeElapsedInMillis = (end - start) / 1000000;
        logger.info(" ###### elapsed time in millis: "+timeElapsedInMillis);

        return result;
    }
```

As for persisting: first, get the req and resp like so:

```
MyRequest req = (MyRequest) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];

MyResponse resp = (MyResponse) result;
```

then it's up to you what you actually want t o persist. For classes with simple fields I'd go with a `varchar`, just remember to override their `toString` methods.

Comment: How can I get request and response as string in this method ?

Comment: I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Minor improvements to the Eric's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65527391/2933389.

```java
@Component
public class MyPayloadCapturingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request)
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response)

        filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper)
        // In the absence of the below line, client will get an empty response body. This helps to copy the response body for the intermidatory operation (audit).
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();

        String requestBody = new String(requestWrapper.contentAsByteArray)
        String responseBody = new String(responseWrapper.contentAsByteArray)
        //..do something with them
    }
}
```